# My redirect class is redirecting me to mysite.com/URLerror

Tags: php

I have created a fuction to redirect my users, but it's redirecting to the wrong page with the addon URLerror

Here's my code:

```
class Redirect
{
    /**
     * To the homepage
     */
    public static function home()
    {
        header("location: " . Config::get('URL'));
    }

    /**
     * To the defined page
     *
     * @param $path
     */
    public static function to($path)
    {
        header("location: " . Config::get('url') . $path);
    }
}
```

Which I am using like so:

```
Redirect::to('dashboard/following?success=5');
```

But it is redirecting to:

http://localhost/user/dashboard/URLerror

My config url is: http://localhost/

It doesn't make sense why it should be doing that as the code looks fine I think

I have tried it with a forward slash before dashboard too, but that is the same result

Comment: Why do you use `URL` in the first one, but `url` in the second one?

Comment: LOL. Fixed. Such a small overlooked mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off:

```
public static function home()
{
    header("location: " . Config::get('URL'));
}

public static function to($path)
{
    header("location: " . Config::get('url') . $path);
}
```

You're using two different styles in the get() string. Unless you are using strtolower on the argument within the get() method, you should use only one. URL or url.

Also, you should think about sanitizing your URL path. try this:

```
header("Location: " . Config::get('URL') . urlencode($path));
```

See how that works.

Another thing, urlencode is going to sanitize / as well, so you should add another parameter.

```
public function to($path, $data = array())
{
    $urldata = "";
    if(!empty($data))
    {
        $count = 0;
        $urldata = "?";
        foreach($data as $item => $value)
        {
            $count++;
            if($count < count($data))
            {
                $urldata .= urlencode($item . "=" . $value . "&");
            }
            else
            {
                $urldata .= urlencode($item . "=" . $value);
            }
        }
    }

    header("Location: " . Config::get('url') . $path . $urldata);
}
```

Keep in mind that function is untested, so you may have to do some work to get it working. But that'll make passing data to a URL easier, especially if you're using a GET request.